# Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: json, rest, jackson, restful-architecture, spring-restcontroller

Currently I am working on rest service, while consuming the service getting error.

```
public String userName;
public String refernceNumber;  
public String requestType;  
public String fullName;  
public String dateOfBirth;  
public String placeOfBirth;  
public String gender;   
public String nationlaity;   
public String telphoneNo;  
public String mobileNo;  
public String note;  
public String email;  
public String processId;   
public List<DocumentDTO> attachmentsList;
```

and my documentdto is like

```
private String doumentNameEng;  
private Integer documentId;  
private String fileName;  
private MultipartFile attachment;  
private String ticketNo;
private String dmsRefId;

enter code here
```

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1171c8a3; line: 1, column: 233] (through reference chain: com.micd.process.dto.applcation["attachmentsList"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:569)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:207)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:464)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2094)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:168)

help me to getout from this error, unable to understand this eror.